# R concatenate every row for each column in a data frame

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame

```
> df <- data.frame(v1,v2)
> df
   v1  v2  
1 aaa 111 
2 bbb 222
```

And i would like to concatenate each row into their respective column resulting in a data.frame like the following:

```
> df
      v1       v2
 1 aaa, bbb 111, 222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `toString` by looping over the columns

```
data.frame(lapply(df, toString))
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   summarise_all(toString)
#        v1       v2
#1 aaa, bbb 111, 222
```